# Writing a portable command line wrapper in C

Tags: c, windows, perl, command-line

I'm writing a perl module called [perl5i](http://github.com/schwern/perl5i).  Its aim is to fix a swath of common Perl problems in one module (using lots of other modules).

To invoke it on the command line for one liners you'd write: `perl -Mperl5i -e 'say "Hello"'`  I think that's too wordy so I'd like to supply a perl5i wrapper so you can write `perl5i -e 'say "Hello"'`.  I'd also like people to be able to write scripts with `#!/usr/bin/perl5i` so it must be a compiled C program.

I figured all I had to do was push "-Mperl5i" onto the front of the argument list and call perl.  And that's what I tried.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * Meant to mimic the shell command
 *     exec perl -Mperl5i "$@"
 *
 * This is a C program so it works in a #! line.
 */

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    /* This value is set by a program which generates this C file */
    const char* perl_cmd = "/usr/local/perl/5.10.0/bin/perl";
    char* perl_args[argc+1];
    perl_args[0] = argv[0];
    perl_args[1] = "-Mperl5i";

    for( i = 1;  i <= argc;  i++ ) {
        perl_args[i+1] = argv[i];
   }

   return execv( perl_cmd, perl_args );
}
```

Windows complicates this approach.  Apparently programs in Windows are not passed an array of arguments, they are passed all the arguments as a single string and then do their own parsing!  Thus something like `perl5i -e "say 'Hello'"` becomes `perl -Mperl5i -e say 'Hello'` and Windows can't deal with the lack of quoting.

So, how can I handle this?  Wrap everything in quotes and escapes on Windows?  Is there a library to handle this for me?  Is there a better approach?  Could I just not generate a C program on Windows and write it as a perl wrapper as it doesn't support #! anyway?

UPDATE: Do be more clear, this is shipped software so solutions that require using a certain shell or tweaking the shell configuration (for example, `alias perl5i='perl -Mperl5i'`) aren't satisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, use a batch file.

perl5i.bat

```
@echo off
perl -Mperl5i %*
```

`%*` is all the command line parameters minus `%0`.

On Unixy systems, a similar shell script will suffice.

**Update:**

I think this will work, but I'm no shell wizard and I don't have an *nix system handy to test.

perl5i

```
#!bash

perl -Mperl5i $@
```

**Update Again:**

DUH! Now I understood your `#!` comment correctly.  My shell script will work from the CLI but not in a `#!` line, since `#!foo` requries that `foo` is a binary file.

Disregard previous update.

It seems like Windows complicates everything.
I think your best there is to use a batch file.

You could [use a file association](http://www.atmaweapon.org/blog/?p=22), associate `.p5i` with `perl -Mperl5i %*`.  Of course this means mucking about in the registry, which is best avoided IMO.  Better to include instructions on how to manually add the association in your docs.

**Yet another update**

You might want to look at how [parl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/script/parl.pod) does it.

Comment: Thanks, I might just punt and use a batch file for Windows.  A shell scripts won't suffice for Unix because #! will only honor compiled programs.

Comment: However, one drawback to batch files on Windows -- ^C-ing out of a batch script will cause a "Terminate Batch Process" prompt.  And for simple wrapper scripts like this, that prompt is near useless, since even if you choose "N", it still terminates perl.

Comment: In Unix your shell should have some form of alias function that makes it even unnecessary to create a shell script.

Comment: Miff, as far as I know, there is no way to suppress the "Terminate" message.

Comment: Thanks @jmucchiello but the purpose is not for my benefit but everyone else who uses the software.  And I'm not content to have people mucking about with their shell configurations.

Comment: You should enclose $@ in double quotes to prevent parameter split. perl -Mperl5i "$@" See bash manual 'Special Parameters' for details.

Comment: Use `perl5i.cmd` not `perl5i.bat`, unless you need it work on Win9x computers.

Comment: @Brad Any particular reason why?

Comment: If you'd rather use a perl/shell script anyway on *nix, you could use /usr/bin/env as a generic binary trampoline.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the behaviour your describe:

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

C:\> ShellCmd.exe a b c
ShellCmd.exe
a
b
c
```

That's with Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Try args in quotes like '-e "say 'hello'"' and note how they get split up.

Comment: Yeah, but that's normal for the Windows shell. I don't see how that makes your wrapper any different from perl itself.

Comment: The wrapper receives "-e", "say 'hello'" on argv.  The quotes around "say 'hello'" have been stripped by the shell.  If you just then pass that along to another program it will get "-e say 'hello'" which Windows doesn't know how to deal with.  The wrapper (more likely the shell) strips the quotes so the internal program doesn't have the benefit of them.  You'd see it if your program tried to call another one with argv.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is always the odd case. Personally, I wouldn't try to code for the Windows environment exception. Some alternatives are using "bat wrappers" or ftype/assoc Registry hacks for a file extension.

Windows ignores the shebang line when running from a DOS command shell, but ironically uses it when CGI-ing Perl in Apache for Windows. I got tired of coding #!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe directly in my web programs because of portability issues when moving to a *nix environment. Instead I created a c:\usr\bin directory on my workstation and copied the perl.exe binary from its default location, typically c:\perl\bin for AS Perl and c:\strawberry\perl\bin for Strawberry Perl. So in web development mode on Windows my programs wouldn't break when migrated to a Linux/UNIX webhost, and I could use a standard issue shebang line "#!/usr/bin/perl -w" without having to go SED crazy prior to deployment. :)

In the DOS command shell environment I just either set my PATH explicitly or create a ftype pointing to the actual perl.exe binary with embedded switch -Mperl5i. The shebang line is ignored.

```
ftype p5i=c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -Mperl5i %1 %*
assoc .pl=p5i
```

Then from the DOS command line you can just call "program.pl" by itself instead of "perl -Mperl5i program.pl"

So the "say" statement worked in 5.10 without any additional coaxing just by entering the name of the Perl program itself, and it would accept a variable number of command line arguments as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx) to build your argv, or just pass your command line directly to [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx).

Of couse, this requires a separate Windows-specific solution, but you said you're okay with that, this is relatively simple, and often coding key pieces specifically to the target system helps integration (from the users' POV) significantly.  YMMV.

If you want to run the same program both with and without a console, you should read [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, at the system level, the command-line is passed to the launched program as a single UTF-16 string, so any quotes entered in the shell are passed as is. So the double quotes from your example are not removed. This is quite different from the POSIX world where the shell does the job of parsing and the launched program receives an array of strings.

I've described here the behavior at the system level. However, between your C (or your Perl) program there is usually the C standard library that is parsing the system command line string to give it to `main()` or `wmain()` as `argv[]`. This is done inside your process, but you can still access the original command line string with [`GetCommandLineW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you really want to control how the parsing is done, or get the string in its full UTF-16 encoding.

To learn more about the Windows command-line parsing quirks, read the following:

- http://www.autohotkey.net/~deleyd/parameters/parameters.htm#WIN
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/15/597984.aspx

You may also be interested by the code of the [wrapper I wrote](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/browser/trunk/Padre/win32/padre.c) for [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) on Win32: this is a GUI program (which means that it will not open a console if launched from the Start menu) called `padre.exe` that embeds perl to launch the `padre` Perl script. It also does a small trick: it changes `argv[0]` to point it to `perl.exe` so that `$^X` will be something usable to launch external perl scripts.

The `execv` you are using in your example code is just an emulation in the C library of the POSIX-like behavior. In particular it will not add quotes around your arguments so that the launched perl works as expected. You have to do that yourself.

Note that due to the fact that the client is responsible for parsing, each client client can do it the way it wants. Many let the libc do it, but not all. So generic command-line generation rules on Windows can not exist: the rule depend on the program launched. 
You may still be interested in "best effort" implementation such as [Win32::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aShellQuote).

Answer (score -1):

If you were able to use C++ then perhaps Boost.Program_options would help:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: Sorry, just bog standard ANSI C 89.  I don't know what compiler they might have available (if any).